# How to return the whole user in successfulAuthentication method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I want to return the user in the response body after sucessful login.
My code:

```
  @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expirationTime))
                .sign(HMAC512(secret.getBytes()));
        res.addHeader(headerString, tokenPrefix + token);

        UsersEntity dbUser = new UsersEntity();
        dbUser = userRepository.findByUserLogin(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername());

        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dbUser);
        res.getWriter().write(json);
        res.flushBuffer();

    }
```

But seems like it doesn't allow to extract the user from DB by username.
I followed the guide: [Guide link](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/)

Comment: but what response do you get with your current implementation? Can you also share your UsersEntity?

Comment: I get empty response body, but the header contains the created token. UsersEntity has fields like userLogin, userName, userPassword, userRole.

Comment: then what do you get in dbUser from userRepository.findByUserLogin(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername()); ? you have userLogin and userName, so shouldn't be userRepository.findByUserName instead? What does userName means in your UserPrincipal?

Comment: [Your code](https://github.com/yukihane/springboot-auth-updated/tree/custom-login-response)([diff](https://github.com/yukihane/springboot-auth-updated/commit/356963112c79b27beb0861976b97e882f2bbb155)) seems run successfully.